# What to do with unused layers in my personal geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, personal-geodatabase, ms-access, remove

I have a question about my personal geodatabase. You can see it at the picture below. [image]

I started with the database in Arcmap with my normal data (Black sea, Danube, East Aegean and West Aegean). In access I added the Excel table with data and linked that data with the layers by the use of queries.

So in Arcmap I'm using the query_.... layers, but the normal ones are still there. Does somebody know if there is a way or if it is possible to remove  the old layers, without this will influence the Query which is half based on the old layers?

I already tried to delete the Records of the old layers in the GBD_GeomColumns table in mc Access, but they still stay visible at the personal geodatabase in arc catalog (I refreshed it). When I delete for example Black Sea the query? Black_sea isn't working anymore because mc Access can't find the normal Black Sea table.

So maybe there is a way how the old layers stay at the database, but aren't visible at ArcCatalog?

Hope someone knows how it works, because it would be a lot more synoptic in use.

Comment: Can you explain how you created your Query_xxx layer? If you have created them and permanently joined the external data then you can simply right click on the "old" featureclasses and delete them, but it is not clear if the link is permanent. Another simple test is create a new empty personal geodatabase, and copy the Query_xxx layer into it. If everything is as you expect then it would be ok to delete them?

Comment: I created them in mc Access. Made the query, linked the "Riverbasin" field which is in the attribute table and in the Exceltable, took the fields I wanted from both tables and saved them. Then added them to the GBD_GeomColumns table with the same Left/bottom/right/top Extent values and the other values, so they also show up in the personal database and on the right place in Arcmap.

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.